# How to map POCO into Record using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper `10.1.1` with .NET 6 (preview) and C# 10. When trying to map a POCO into a `record`, it fails for a nested property.

Please see the following code:

```cs
using AutoMapper;
using FluentAssertions;
using NUnit.Framework;

// All the following stuff is necessary to be used with EF Core
// ReSharper disable AutoPropertyCanBeMadeGetOnly.Local
// ReSharper disable UnusedMember.Global
#pragma warning disable 8618

namespace Tests.UnitTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class MyTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void MappingTest()
        {
            var book = new Book(new Person("Oscar"));
            var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(x => x.AddProfile<AutoMapperProfile>()).CreateMapper();

            var result = mapper.Map<Book, ExistingBook>(book);

            result.CreatedBy.Should().Be(book.CreatedBy.Name);
        }
    }

    public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
    {
        public AutoMapperProfile() => CreateMap<Book, ExistingBook>().ForMember(x => x.CreatedBy, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.CreatedBy.Name));
    }

    public record ExistingBook(string CreatedBy);

    public class Person
    {
        public Person()
        {
        }

        public Person(string name) => Name = name;

        public string Name { get; private set; }
    }

    public class Book
    {
        public Book()
        {
        }

        public Book(Person createdBy) => CreatedBy = createdBy;

        public Person CreatedBy { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

When executing `MappingTest()`, it fails with `Expected result.CreatedBy to be "Oscar" with a length of 5, but "Tests.UnitTests.Person" has a length of 22, differs near "Tes" (index 0).`.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: You need `ForCtorParam`.

Comment: Ah great - thank you! Do you want to post your solution as answer?

Comment: Btw.: From my experience it can be simpler to remove automapper and use `FromXy()` functions on your records. If your records need all data as ctor params, the compiler will ensure everything is fine, so no need to add tests in most cases. And in the end it was less code in most of our projects)

Comment: @ChristophLütjen You mean you'd create a method `ExistingBook.FromBook()`  and do the mapping manually?

Comment: Exactly. If your ctor needs all properties as parameters (as in your example) the compiler will ensure, all properties are mapped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mapping through the constructor here. So you need `ForCtorParam`.

```
CreateMap<Book, ExistingBook>().ForCtorParam(nameof(ExistingBook.CreatedBy), options => options.MapFrom(book => book.CreatedBy.Name));
```

Comment: Thank you. Please just add the following snippet to your answer and I'll accept and uprate your answer: `CreateMap<Book, ExistingBook>().ForCtorParam(nameof(ExistingBook.CreatedBy), options => options.MapFrom(book => book.CreatedBy.Name));`